Why did Mr Bob Jansen unilaterally delete questions on a high schooler's questions on studying Quantitative Finance?
Moderator Bob Jansen commented

I'm having trouble convincing myself you're not trolling here.

I certainly was not trolling, but Mr Jansen deleted both questions. Please counsel me how I can improve them. 
https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/53983
https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/53984

At best they are asking for career advice and therefore off-topic. I see no way to make this question an on topic one.

You are far kinder than I would have been to a high-school kid.
